# adjust width of select2 if/when it opens

Tags: jquery-select2, bootstrap-4

I have a select2 in a bootstrap v4 dropdown.  I load the options into the select2 when the dropdown is triggered.

The select2 contains some items with long names, and if the select2 is opened, I would like to show the full width even though that is wider than the dropdown.

I have tried `select2({width: 'resolve'})` and `select2({width: '200%'})`
in the `select2:opening` and `select2:open` event handlers but they throw exceptions.  If I initialize the select2 with width:200%, it is too big if it isn't opened.

Is this possible?  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the `dropdownAutoWidth` option. This should automatically resize the dropdown based on the available room.

Comment: Thanks.  I added `dropdownAutowidth: true` and width: "resolve" and this  definitely helped, the dropdown is wider although not wide enough.  Looked at https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3101, and it seems that maybe what I need is 4.0.3?